# Proper tables with multicols

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, multicol

Is there a way to tell `multicol` to leave space at the top of the cols > 1?

The main gotcha is that the table data will be shared and I don't want to chop it up for different places but have the compiler figure it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox

\newcounter{entryno}
\setcounter{entryno}{1}

\begin{document}

\section*{I want this:}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
      Cap a
        & Cap b\\\hline
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      {}
        & {}\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
  }\unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}

\section*{Or this:}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
      Cap a
        & Cap b\\\hline
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Cap a
        & Cap b\\\hline
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
  }\unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}


\section*{Not this:}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
    \makeatletter\col@number\@ne
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
      Cap a
        & Cap b\\\hline
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
    \end{longtable}
    \unskip
    \unpenalty
    \unpenalty
  }\unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to have that automatic would require the authors of `multicol` and `longtable` to talk to each other. We've only known each other for 25 years so not really had time to discuss this yet.

Comment: 25 years is indeed a bit early to discuss topics like this - what about 26 years + 1 year implementation?

On a more serious note, I guess this means that there is "no way" at the moment?

Comment: it's trickier than it ought to be. Sorry:-)

Comment: as a workaround I would probably take the heading out of the longtable, then under the `\section` add a full width tabular with effectively a double column header that sits over all four table columns. if your tabular is p cols of known width that is easy, with `l` it's a bit harder but you could (perhaps) get the widths out of the longtable data in the aux file.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the table is in a column "mode" (if columns equal 2 add {}&{}\\)? That way I could keep my data in one place and add the workaround from my "I want this" example? Else I would have to define my own variables for that.

Comment: you mean `\ifnum\col@number=2` ?

Comment: NEVERMIND - Thank you! I commented the makeatletter - stupid me. ~~~~ Yes! Just that it tells me that: Undefined control sequence. ... Missing number, treated as zero. ... Missing = inserted for \ifnum ... Missing number, treated as zero. Edit: + If I have no columns at all.

Comment: @Eyenseo If you solved your problem you may answer your own question...

Answer (score 2):

With the information form David Carlisle I came up with the following environment and helper command.

This will *not* break nicely at the end of a page but will behave like a minipage. 
The environment is used to hide all the nastiness and the command to specify different balance cells depending on the amount of columns.

Here is my workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

%-------------------
% Workaround for multicols containing tables
%
% Sets \myMultiCols to \col@number
%  and \col@number to 1
%-------------------
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\mtcbox
\newenvironment{myTableCols}[1]{%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}%
  \setbox\mtcbox\vbox\bgroup%
  \edef\myMultiCols{\the\col@number}%
  \col@number\@ne%
}{%
  \unskip%
  \unpenalty%
  \unpenalty\egroup%
  \unvbox\mtcbox%
  \end{multicols}%
  \vspace*{-.35\baselineskip}% TODO check if needed
}
\makeatother
% This fixes the horrendous layout for
\newcommand{\myBalanceColIfColums}[1]{%
  \ifdefined\myMultiCols\ifnum\myMultiCols=#1%
    \\%
  \fi\fi%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{myTableCols}{2}
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
      Cap a
        & Cap b\\\hline
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      \myBalanceColIfColums{3}
      Data
        & Data\\
      \myBalanceColIfColums{2}
      Data
        & Data\\
      \myBalanceColIfColums{3}
      Data
        & Data\\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{myTableCols}

  \begin{myTableCols}{3}
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
      Cap a
        & Cap b\\\hline
      Data
        & Data\\
      Data
        & Data\\
      \myBalanceColIfColums{3}
      Data
        & Data\\
      \myBalanceColIfColums{2}
      Data
        & Data\\
      \myBalanceColIfColums{3}
      Data
        & Data\\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{myTableCols}
\end{document}
```

[image]